# Explore the ado agent task time, Simplejson plugin encounter error:Authentication to data source failed

Tags: azure-devops, grafana, azure-devops-rest-api, simplejson

I am new user for this plugin,not sure is it some configure issue.

I want to explore the ado agent task work time in grafana.I can get the json data according offical document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pool-consumption-report?view=azure-devops

and the ado agent api:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project_id}/_odata/v4.0-preview/TaskAgentRequestSnapshots
```

I have installed the simplejson plugin,and input the right user and passwd.After i click save and test,there is an error:
Authentication to data source failed
I am not sure is there some configure issue? or could someone share some advice how to explore the ado agent task work time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used a new grafana plugin infinity,and it works well.

[image]